# How to catch Spring Batch's ItemStreamException after @Retryable maxAttempts exceeded?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-retry

I have the following `ItemReader`:

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.LineMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Retryable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MyReader extends FlatFileItemReader<Holding> {

    @Autowired
    public MyReader(LineMapper<Holding> lineMapper, File loadFile) {
        setResource(new FileSystemResource(loadFile));
        final int NUMBER_OF_HEADER_LINES = 1;
        setLinesToSkip(NUMBER_OF_HEADER_LINES);
        setLineMapper(lineMapper);
    }

    @Override
    @Retryable(value=ItemStreamException.class, maxAttempts=5,  backoff=@Backoff(delay=1800000))
    public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
                super.open(executionContext);
    }
}
```

After the 5th attempt, ItemStreamException is thrown if the `loadFile` does not exist. How can I catch this exception?

I want to handle this exception by sending an email to an admin. I've tried surrounding `jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);` with the try catch clause but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure a retry interceptor as a bean and specify it in the `interceptor` property; there's a `RetryInterceptorBuilder` to help with assembling the bean.

You can add a recoverer to the interceptor which is called after retries are exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply skippable-exception-classes for your reader so Spring Batch will not fail the job.

For sending email in case failed, I would suggest you for with Job Listener instead of try/catch.

Nghia